# 'bodyParser' is deprecated in node v14

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

code :

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
})
```

I have installed body-parser with npm i body-parser and required it. But it shows "bodyParser" is deprecated with a crossed line in app.use(bodyParser)

node version : v14.17.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`body-parser` is not deprecated in node 14, it's deprecated in [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html).

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: so, we do not need body-parser to use req.body ?

Comment: Correct, we no longer need to import the `body-parser` library, its functionality is included in the express object.